# meu comando sql nao esta salvando porque?

Tags: php, sql

estou salvando no banco de dados , mas hora que clico em salvar nao vai escreve nome repetido que foi o que eu coloquei pra validar ,e o botao nao salva no sql

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QUESTIONARIO ARGUS</title>
</head>

<section>
<a href="cadastros.php"><img src="emblema2.png" alt="" id="emblema"></a>
<h1>QUESTIONARIO ARGUS</h1>
<p>SELECIONE SEU NOME</p>
<body>
<form method="post" action="processafoto.php">
    <input type="submit"  value="Salvar"  class="btn">
   <input type="reset" value="Limpar" class="btn">
  <br><br>

     <select name="nomes" id="funcionarios"  required autofocus>
     <option value="Alipio Jonathas Tanan Silva">Alipio Jonathas Tanan Silva</option>
     <option value="Alyne Roris">Alyne Roris</option>
</select>


<p>ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPÇÕES PARA A FOTO </p>
   <div class="quizfotos">
  <img src="imagens/foto1.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotoum" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotoum" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto2.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotodois" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotodois" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto3.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fototres" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fototres" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto4.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotoquatro" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotoquatro" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto5.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotocinco" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotocinco" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto6.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotoseis" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotoseis" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto7.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotosete" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotosete" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto8.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotooito" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotooito" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto9.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotonove" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotonove" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto10.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotodez" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotodez" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto11.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotoonze" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotoonze" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <img src="imagens/foto12.jpeg" alt=""><br>
  <input type="radio" name="fotodoze" value="OK" class="quiz"required >
  <label for="OK" class="quiz">OK</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="fotodoze" value="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz">
  <label for="Olhando pra Baixo"class="quiz"> Olhando pra Baixo</label>
  <br><br><br><br>


 </div>

  </section>         


PHP  <?php 

include_once("conexao.php");

$nome =   $_POST['nomes'];
$fotoum =  $_POST['fotoum'];
$fotodois =  $_POST['fotodois'];
$fototres =  $_POST['fototres'];
$fotoquatro =  $_POST['fotoquatro'];
$fotocinco =  $_POST['fotocinco'];
$fotoseis =  $_POST['fotoseis'];
$fotosete =  $_POST['fotosete'];
$fotooito =  $_POST['fotooito'];
$fotonove =  $_POST['fotonove'];
$fotodez = $_POST['fotodez'];
$fotoonze = $_POST['fotoonze'];
$fotodoze = $_POST['fotodoze'];

$sql = "insert into quizfoto (nome,foto1,,foto2,foto3,foto4,foto5,foto6,foto7,foto8,foto9,foto10,foto11,foto12) 
values ('$nome' , '$fotoum', '$fotodois', '$fototres', '$fotoquatro', '$fotocinco',
'$fotoseis', '$fotosete', '$fotooito', '$fotonove','$fotodez', '$fotoonze', '$fotodoze')";

$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql); //comando para salvar query

$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Questionário Argus</title>
</head>
<body>
<div className="container">
    <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
    <a href="#"><img src="Argusss.png" alt="" class="imagem"></a>

     <a href="quizfoto.php"><li>VOLTAR</li></a>   


    </ul>

    </nav>
<section>
    <h1>Confirmação Questionário de Funcionarios</h1>
    <hr><br><br>

    <?php 
    if($linhas == 1){
print "<p style='color:white;'> QUESTIONÁRIO RESPONDIDO COM SUCESSO </p> ";
}else{
print "<p style='color:red;'> NOME REPETIDO OU FALTA RESPONDER ALGUMA QUESTÃO</p> ";

}

    ?>

</section>
</div>```
````

Comment: O que os logs do seu servidor dizem sobre o erro?

Comment: Tem uma vírgula extra na SQL query `(nome,foto1,,foto2,`. Tente fazer o que @Woss sugeriu, ver as mensagens de erro. Se nenhuma mensagem estiver sendo mostrada, use este código `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` para mostrar todas as mensagens de erros ERROR, WARNING e E_NOTICE.

Comment: obrigado qndo vc esta programando a muito tempo vc nao enxerga essas virgulas ,desculpe minha ingenuidade era essa bendita virgula o erro e eu nao enxergava

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Publiquei uma resposta para novos visitantes. Se você aceitá-la como resposta (clicar no V na esquerda) já fecha essa pergunta. Obg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem uma vírgula extra na SQL query entre **foto1** e **foto2**

```
$sql = "insert into quizfoto (nome,foto1,,foto2, //..
```

Tenta fazer o que @Woss sugeriu, ver as mensagens de erro. Se nenhuma mensagem estiver sendo mostrada, use o código abaixo no início do arquivo para mostrar todas as mensagens de erros ERROR, WARNING, NOTICE etc.

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Documentação de [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).